# FB API "100 continue" & "500 Internal Server Error" (error_subcode 99)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a peculiar issue with the Facebook API. I think it probably has to do with high volume, but that has not brought me any closer to the solution. When posting out messages to Facebook API, I occasionally receive an error such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 19:22:38 GMT

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
facebook-api-version: v2.3
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-trace-id: El4BfeJo4vI
x-fb-rev: 2746767
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: F3xHF4IY15E3VK9M5acge9B6jBKOEqwP2Ob4F8WsoYRkGeAiY2PkzOjiiawhQ/Uq0TT/Xen+JLZtFXA9ZUsbRg==
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 19:23:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 77

{"error":{"code":1,"message":"An unknown error occurred","error_subcode":99}}
```

Usually retries later will work for the same request so it would not appear to be the culprit. The issue here, however, is that the message still *sometimes* appears to go through. How should such responses be handled?

I read on the Continue header, but I'm none the wiser now - especially since it comes with a non-descriptive 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: I'll get this error inconsistently, and have to do retries a few minutes later to get a good result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fb-reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBbMI.png)

"An unknown error occurred","code":1,"error_subcode":99"

Reason for above error according to facebook:

This error code is an indication that your request timed out. It may be the case that the request is valid, however the maximum processing time for the API was exceeded. Recommendation: Wait a few minutes, and then try again. If the problem persists, please continue filing a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably safely ignore the 100 header; it's correctly been followed up as you have another response (the 500).

You should never really get a a 500 from any site: means their code is broken. Should report it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Indeed, I did. Hopefully I'll get some light to this from there. Was hoping someone has a workaround.

Comment: No change as of June 2018. This error_subcode 99 occurs intermittently on e.g. queries for graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_nnnn/campaigns . Retry with no changes and it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

It has been [reported](https://m.facebook.com/groups/pmdcommunity/?view=permalink&id=1174638509255282) several times that a too long request will result in this type of error-subcodes (99). Try to narrow your request parameters while Facebook doesn't support long requests. (Although the 500 error looks new to me.)

Comment: Yeah, the request in question is a simple post though, so it shouldn't be a timeout in that sense. The weird part is that it sometimes works and still gives the error.

Answer (score -2):

You should use pagination as this document:
https://m.facebook.com/groups/pmdcommunity/?view=permalink&id=1174638509255282